# Multiline f-string in Python """ """ turning other code lines into strings outside of what I am looking for

Tags: python, f-string

I am trying to e-mail an attachment and am formatting the content of my e-mail message.

For some reason when I do:

```
 variable = f"""
    email content formatting line 1
    email content formatting line 2
    email content formatting line 3
    """
```

The lines inside the `""" """` don't all turn to string, and the rest of my code below becomes string. Any ideas why?

For example, the `msg_text` and `msg.attach` lines turn into string. How do I fix my f-string setup?

```
html = f"""
    <html><body>
    <h1> Monthly Accounting File ({month_end.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")})</h1>
    <p>{df.to_html(index=False)}</p>
    </body></html>
    """
msg_text = MIMEText(html, 'html')
msg.attach(msg_text)
```

If I add one space after `f` then my lines turn to string but I thought that wasn't the correct syntax for f-strings. This is for Jupyter Notebook Python 3.0. See below for example:

```
html = f """
    <html><body>
    <h1> Monthly Accounting File ({month_end.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")})</h1>
    <p>{df.to_html(index=False)}</p>
    </body></html>
    """
msg_text = MIMEText(html, 'html')
msg.attach(msg_text)
```

Comment: are you sure you pasted the sample code correctly?

Comment: Maybe there are `"""` somewhere else in the code?

Comment: There are no other """ between the code i sent you. It is a direct copy paste

Comment: what you pasted in the first snippet is the correct Python syntax (while a space between the 'f' and quotes is a syntax error ) - are you sure the cells you are putting this in JuPyter are set as Python cells? 

Or maybe it could be just a highlight bug in the version you are running, and it will work just ok? (I find it very little likely, but it might be the case)

Comment: @jsbueno you are correct...i kept it the same format and it worked just fine...It just looks wrong in the version I am running.

Answer (score 2):

Making multi-line f-strings is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54950733/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49416074/8508004), as well as other places. **In this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75967185/8508004) multi-line f-strings inside a multi-line triple-quoted string work with only the `f` marking it as an f-string being invoked on the first line.** Note though there and here tried to have indenting on the rest of the lines. I found I had to remove the indentation to get it to work.

I sometimes call the triple-quoted string assignments 'docstrings', but they are actually different. For completeness, here using a Python docstring with f-strings is different. This [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70865657/8508004) covers fairly well how "Docstrings in Python must be regular string literals."